# Bicep Validation Error: Storage account does not accept BlockBlobStorage ask SKU

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-storage, azure-bicep

Im trying to create a storage account with bicep in West Europe.

I get the following error:

```
{"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment", "message": "The template deployment 'bicep-deployment-from-ground-up' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '1a94c0f3-1bf2-4b71-8f03-0a2689129899'. See inner errors for details."}

Inner Errors:
{"code": "PreflightValidationCheckFailed", "message": "Preflight validation failed. Please refer to the details for the specific errors."}

Inner Errors:
{"code": "InvalidValuesForRequestParameters", "target": "dtcontent", "message": "Values for request parameters are invalid: kind, sku. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/storageaccounttypes"}

Inner Errors:
{"code": "InvalidValuesForRequestParameters", "target": "dtcontent", "message": "Values for request parameters are invalid: kind."}
```

The bicep looks like this:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource dtcontent 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'dtcontent'
  location: location
  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }

  resource blobService 'blobServices@2023-01-01' = {
    name: 'default'

    resource content 'containers@2023-01-01' = {
      name: 'content'
      properties: {
        publicAccess: 'Container'        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Im using az cli with 2.57.0 and bicep version 0.25.53. Does someone now how to fix this error?

Comment: Change the Api version to `2022-05-01` instead of `2023-01-01` and retry the deploying the storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my environment, I'm using the **`az cli`** with version 2.56.0 and **`bicep`** version 0.25.53.

According to this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-feature-support-in-storage-accounts), the **`Premium`** access tier is the default value for premium block blob storage account type and cannot be changed for the premium block blob storage account type.

You don't need to pass the **`access tier`** in the bicep code and also make sure your deployment resource group is in the same location.

In my environment, I tried with the script below using the **`westeurope`** location.

**Code:**

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource dtcontent 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'dtcontent2'
  location: location
  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
  }

  resource blobService 'blobServices@2023-01-01' = {
    name: 'default'

    resource content 'containers@2023-01-01' = {
      name: 'content'
      properties: {
        publicAccess: 'Container'        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Deployment command:**

```
az deployment group create --resource-group v-venkat --template-file ./sample.bicep
```

Here, **`v-venkat`** is a resource group with a **`westeurope`** location.

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)